# how to find who is holding the lock of a file in RCS

Tags: linux, unix, version-control, rcs

Suppose I lock a file which is controlled by RCS

```
[root@host1:/etc/yp]# co -l group auto_home
RCS/group,v  -->  group
revision 1.6103 (locked)
done
RCS/auto_home,v  -->  auto_home
revision 1.4003 (locked)
done
[root@host1:/etc/yp]#
```

I see the files with ",v" generated in RCS directory

```
[root@host1:/etc/yp/RCS]# ls -lrth | tail -3
-r--r--r--   1 root     other        16M Feb 20 12:20 passwd,v
-r--r--r--   1 root     other       3.5M Feb 21 23:03 group,v
-r--r--r--   1 root     other       4.1M Feb 21 23:03 auto_home,v
[root@host1:/etc/yp/RCS]#
```

Can we determine who is holding the lock file?
All of the admins use the "root" login for making the changes ( by sudo -s to become root)

If someone has already locked, I see the below message

```
[root@campyp:/etc/yp]# co -l group
RCS/group,v  -->  group
revision 1.6103 (locked)
writable group exists; remove it? [ny](n): ^C
RCS: Interrupt
RCS: Cleaning up.
[root@campyp:/etc/yp]#
```

Can we check who has locked the file?

Comment: If the user is logged in as root when they lock the file, then root has the lock.  If you are logged in as root, then you have the lock.  This is why doing things like this as root is a *really* bad idea!

Answer (score 3):

In RCS, locks are stored in the header of the archive-file.  Here is an example header to illustrate:

```
head    1.1;
access
        thomas;
symbols;
locks
        thomas:1.1; strict;
comment @# @;

1.1
date    2014.08.14.00.40.55;    author thomas;  state Exp;
branches;
next    ;

desc
@@
```

The `rlog` command gives that header information:

```
$ rlog 2linux,v

RCS file: 2linux,v
Working file: 2linux
head: 1.1
branch:
locks: strict
        thomas: 1.1
access list:
        thomas
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 1;     selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1    locked by: thomas;
date: 2014/08/14 00:40:55;  author: thomas;  state: Exp;
RCS_BASE
=============================================================================
```

By default, the *author* of a lock is determined by checking [environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/rcs.html#Environment) `LOGNAME` and `USER`.  Those are set when your users `sudo`, e.g., to "root".  But the behavior can be overridden:

- When you `sudo`, the original `$USER` is saved in `SUDO_USER`.  One could reset `$LOGNAME` and `$USER` from `$SUDO_USER`, making locks correspond to the real users.
- RCS is documented to support setuid operation with the files owned by *root*.  You may be able to use that, rather than having your users `sudo`.

Further reading:

- [rlog(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlog)
- [rcsfile(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rcsfile)
- [ci(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ci) (see discussion of *setuid*)

Answer (score 1):

No. If all your users are `root`, then the lock will always belong to `root`.

This is a dubious arrangement at best, anyway. Have users commit edits as themselves; there should be no sane reason to do these things as `root` in the first place.